# Display Flex not working in Mac OS and iPhone 6

Tags: ios, css, iphone, macos, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox in my project and turns out that it doesn't work in Mac OS(Chrome) and iPhone 6(Chrome), but it works perfectly on Windows,Linux and on browsers Chrome,Firefox and Opera.

I added cross browser support code for flex but still no luck.

```
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
```

Here is codepen:

http://codepen.io/nikasv/pen/VjxLJL

Here is the image of how it look on Windows and Linux, Browsers(Chrome,Firefoz and Opera) and How it looks on iPhone 6 and same look is on iMac

[image]

Am I missing anything seems that I added every cross browser compatibility style for flexbox. Is there a problem with calc? Would appreciate your help. Thanks.